# How to make vite resolve assets referenced in url() in sass files imported in react component library (installed as a package)?

Tags: reactjs, npm, sass, vite

We are using Vite to build a react application, which in dependency has a package we also maintain with published source for react components in typescript, styling in sass, and bundled along with assets.

I want to be able from the consumer react project to have vite bundle everything when encountered through import in react files, and not added manually to the a public dir, but vite seems not to find or serve the assets, in the browser it tries to resolve from "http://localhost:8080/assets/images/bg.png" which get a 404.

Suppose for the example that I have the package structure as follow :

```
.
├── package.json
├── assets
│   └── images
│       └── bg.png
└── src
    ├── index.ts
    ├── lib
    │   └── my-component.tsx
    └── scss
        └── my-component.scss
```

I have a simple React component from the package below.

```
import React from 'react'

import '../scss/my-component.scss'

export const MyComponent = () => (
    <div class="custom-bg"></div>
)
```

A simple scss file below :

```scss
.custom {
    background-image: url('../../assets/images/bg.png');
}
```

And in the project that import it from node_module I have this one :

```
import React from 'react'
import { MyComponent } from 'my-package'

export const App = () => (
    <MyComponent />
)
```

I expect vite to resolve the source in the dependency, sees that it imports a sass file, sees that the sass file imports an assets with relative path, and copy or serve the asset in the public dir. Should it not work that way ?